# How Do I Insert Scraped Data Into My Database Using Django Without Duplicates

Tags: django

I scraped some data off the web on the developing pandemic using django, but my problem is that whenever i refresh my app on the browser it inserts same records over and over again into my database and keeps rendering them on my template.

```
# My Model.py

    class cases(models.Model):
    states = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    total_cases = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    active_cases = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    discharged = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    death_cases = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.states

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cases'

# My view.py
        states = []
        total = []
        active = []
        discharge = []
        death = []
        zipped_record = (zip(states,total,active,discharge,death))   

# moving records gotten to database

   def index(request):
      try:
         for(state, totals, actives, discharges, deaths) in zipped_record:
            cases.objects.create(states=state,
                         total_cases=totals,
                         active_cases=actives,
                         discharged=discharges,
                         death_cases=deaths)
      except:
        print('Records already exists')
      context = {'cases': cases.objects.all()}
      return render(request,'pandemicHome.html',context)
# My template
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="case_table">
    <tr>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">S/N</th>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">State</th>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">Total Cases</th>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">Active Cases</th>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">Discharged Cases</th>
       <th style="font-size: 18px">Death Cases</th>
     </tr>
     {% for case in cases %}
     <tr class="table_rows">
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{forloop.counter}}</td>
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{case.states}}</td>
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{case.total_cases}}</td>
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{case.active_cases}}</td>
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{case.discharged}}</td>
       <td style="font-size: 18px">{{case.death_cases}}</td>
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Okay changed now

Comment: Have you tried to use get_or_create instead of create?

Comment: no will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**At first,** you can't set any flag that can check or match that your scrape data already exists in your databases.

If Check or match exists you can run this [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
cases.objects.get_or_create(states=state,total_cases=totals,active_cases=actives,discharged=discharges,death_cases=deaths)
```

And every time you didn't scrape data. You can separate your URL when you need to scrape data you can use (create query) URL otherwise you use other URLs. When you show data to your website you can run this [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects) `all_entries = cases.objects.all()`

You can write a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job for a time-based job scheduler. When you need to scrape data you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (state, totals, actives, discharges, deaths) in zipped_record:
        if not cases.objects.filter(states=state,
                                            total_cases=totals,
                                            active_cases=actives,
                                            discharged=discharges,
                                            death_cases=deaths).exists():
            cases.objects.create(states=state,
                                         total_cases=totals,
                                         active_cases=actives,
                                         discharged=discharges,
                                         death_cases=deaths)
except:
    print('Records already exists')
```

I think i just got it all figured out already... What do you think about this?